# Android Re-create service at given intervals using AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I have read about this `AlarmManager`, but it's still a bit confusing to me.
So I have a `Service` in my app, which I want to run all the time (its a medicinal app, so its supposed to **notify** the user the whole time its being used), but even though its a `Service`, **Android kills it from time to time**, so I want to **schedule** it to be recreated in like **30mins interval**, and then scheduled again. How can I do it?

Comment: for that you have to use AlarmManager

Comment: I know, thats what I am asking, how to use the AlarmManager to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For started services, there are two additional major modes of operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them. See the linked documentation for more detail on the semantics.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I have read about START_STICKY but it seems there are some reported bugs that it doesnt recreates the service, so I guessed I'd better use AlarmManager...

Comment: I use services for a rabbitMQ connection, seems to work fine. Don't know a lot about AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

Study this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)... for implementing **HOW TO CREATE ALARM MANAGER**

**CREATE ALARM MANAGER CLASS**

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

 // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
//20 minutes.


alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

**ADD THIS TO MANIFEST**

```
<receiver android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `AlarmReciever.class` is a class which you want to set for repeating every definite time interval.